# Ubuntu 19.04 not starting after upgrading to 19.10

Tags: 19.04, boot-repair

I upgraded ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 and it started working a few hours ago but later when I turned on my laptop (lenovo B50) ubuntu isn't starting or it is lagging and freezing with a black screen. How can I fix it?

Comment: Consider adding details about your situation. For instance, are you dual-booting with another OS such as Windows, have you tried any troubleshooting steps already?

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall Ubuntu 19.04 with the **iso** file instead of the update, it will be more effective.